# Disable eslint warning

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

Anchor used as a button. Anchors are primarily expected to navigate. Use the button element instead. (jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid)

I would like to disable the above warning.

So i write

```
<div data-g-id={this.props.g.id}>
  (// eslint-disable-next-line anchor-is-valid)
  <a
    className='classname'
    href="#"
    data-point="TL"
    onClick={this.callFunction}
   >
</div>
```

But the above one is not working.

Comment: Can you add atleast one more line?

Comment: @16kb Updated the question

Comment: Do you know if eslint is run on the `jsx` file or on the output `js` file? Cause comments might not make it to the `js` ones?

Comment: Use `{}` instead of `()`

Comment: @HoriaComan I did not get your point. Please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: `jsx` files get compiled to `js` files. Depending on how `eslint` is setup, you might run it on the `jsx` ones or on the resulting `js` files. If it's the latter, comments might not be preserved when transforming them, so `eslint` would not know to disable the warning.

Comment: @HoriaComan Now I get your point. So what can I do in my case. I can't change my anchor tag to button here. It will affect my whole application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
{
  // eslint-disable-next-line anchor-is-valid
}
<a
...
```

instead of `()`

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it globally in `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0
  }
}
```